# Deactivate plugin for a specific user group

Tags: plugins, actions, user-roles

I would like to deactivate a plugin for a specific user. I'm using the following code inside a the `wp-content/plugin-mu` plugin file:

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'bo_disable_apm_plugin' );


    function bo_disable_apm_plugin( $plugins ) {

    global $current_user;

    // Not use advanced page manager for media manager
    if ( is_admin() && in_array( 'media_manager', $current_user->roles ) ) {
      $key = array_search( 'advanced-page-manager/advanced_page_manager.php' , $plugins );
      if ( false !== $key ) {
        unset( $plugins[$key] );
      }
    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

Of course, it's not working. I don't understand the way `option_active_plugins`. By dumping data, I find out the code is executed 7 times.

On the first loop, the user is not know, so the condition is not met. The plugin is still activated.

I have added a more complicated code with three conditionnal : unset the plugin if the user is not set, so the plugin is inactivated each time on the first loop. IF the user is set (next loops), check him to set/unset the plugin accordingly. Wasn't working either.

I didn't manage to find the right formula, so maybe I'm wrong somewhere and it can't be done. Each time, the plugin is either activated or deactivated for all users. It looks like the first iteration is the one that counts.

Is there a way to inactivate a plugin for specific user/group ?

Comment: First time the option is called active plugins are loaded (just a `require_once`) so even if in later calls the plugin is filtered out from options, plugin file is already required, and doesn't exist a way to remove it. So yes, first time is the only that count. The problem is that in WordPress user login is handled quite after plugins are loaded and this is the reason why your code fails. You have 2 options: force user login earlier; or remove the features plugin adds, i.e. I guess plugin adds some hooks, wait until `wp_loaded` and then remove all of them. Plugin will be active but "muted".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping to avoid 'unhooking' all features from the plugin (in case they add more in a update), but... You suggest a way to "force login earlier" ? Is that even possible ?

Comment: Maybe you should place your comment as an answer, you answered it (negatively, but yet).

Comment: If I have time today I'll answer properly, showing a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Would love to have your insights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer to this [Disable plugin / plugin action via theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/disable-plugin-plugin-action-via-theme) is good for base knowledge on how to disable plugins from code.

Adapting that knowledge to your needs will leave us with this:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_filter_the_plugins');    
function my_filter_the_plugins()
{
    global $current_user;
    if (in_array('media_manager', $current_user->roles)) {
        deactivate_plugins( // deactivate for media_manager
            array(
                '/advanced-page-manager/advanced_page_manager.php'
            ),
            true, // silent mode (no deactivation hooks fired)
            false // network wide
        );
    } else { // activate for those than can use it
        activate_plugins(
            array(
                '/advanced-page-manager/advanced_page_manager.php'
            ),
            '', // redirect url, does not matter (default is '')
            false, // network wise
            true // silent mode (no activation hooks fired)
        );
    }
}
```

Basically this happens:

For the `media_manager` user group the `my_filter_the_plugins` disables(*silently*) the `advanced-page-manager` plugin. We then need to reactivate the plugin(*silently*, again) for those that aren't in the `media_manager` user group.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know about the function to deactivate a plugin. Let me test that soon and come back here to answer the question and report results.

Comment: @Simon I've tested the code on a website that I am working on. Worked for me.

Comment: How did you go with this @Simon? Don't forget to come back and let us know how you went - and accept this answer (using the check mark on the left) if it helped you. At the moment, it is coming up in our 'unanswered questions' list :)

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook did you read the comments? It activates & deactivates them silently and does not fire activation & deactivation hooks.

Comment: Doh - my bad - deleted comment in the interests of not misleading people

Comment: @TimMalone Actually, I solved the problem a different way and did not tried this solution - that's why I did not mark the question as answered - because I can't tell if this is a solution for this problem for sure. Let me know if I should - aifrim says it works.

Comment: @Simon In the end it's up to you, but it does help 'resolve' the issue to mark it as answered. You can read more about how this works here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I can confirm the code works as expected on my test.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically deactivate whole plugin only based on the information you have at wordpress "boot" time, which is basically the URL and cookies. Any check more complex then that will probably have to wait until boot is completed to be able to be executed, at which time the plugin is already loaded and it is too late to "deactivate" it.