# WordPress Multisite: Programmatically Activate / Deactivate a Plugin of a Specific Blog

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite

Programmatically, I want to activate / deactivate a plugin of this specific blog/site in a WordPress Multisite. Any help will be gladly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `switch_to_blog()`, `activate_plugins()`, and `deactivate_plugins()`.

You can put this in functions.php, but you'll want to remove it once it runs:

```
// hook to admin init
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_swap_plugins');
function wpse_swap_plugins() {
    // set blog ID per your needs
    $blog_id = 3;
    // switch to the site where you want to activate/deactivate plugins
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    // activate: set your path, don't set redirect,
    // don't make this network wide, don't prevent activation hooks
    activate_plugins(array(
        '/full/path/to/plugin/you/want/to/activate.php'
    ), '', false, false);
    // deactivate: same arguments as activate
    deactivate_plugins(array(
        '/full/path/to/plugin/to/deactivate.php'
    ), '', false, false);
    // switch context back to original site
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Credit to related answer: [Deactivate plugin for a specific user group](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159085/deactivate-plugin-for-a-specific-user-group)

Comment: You can also use [`is_plugin_active()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/) to check if the plugin is active before you activate/deactivate it.

Comment: This is well explained. Thank you so much guys! 
How about for theme? **Programmatically Activate / Deactivate the theme of a Specific Blog**

Answer (score 0):

**Via WP-CLI**

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/activate/

**Syntax:**

```
wp plugin activate <plugin(s)> --url=<url>
```

---

**Example:**

1. `wp plugin activate akismet --url="foo.example.com"`
2. `wp plugin activate akismet jetpack ninja-forms --url="bar.example.com"`