# Execute plugin for specific user role(s) only

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

How can I have specific plugins only active for one specific user role (or potentially an array of user roles)?

Is there something I can add to my `functions.php` in the child theme to only use a specific plugin for a specific user role?

I have tried various answers from here and articles but nothing seems to offer what I need.

**Update:**

I've tried the below code (as a test) and it works in that if an admin accesses the site it disables the plugin, but once it's disabled it stays disabled for everyone. It needs to asses the current user and activate or reactivate depending on their role.

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'custom_plugin_load_filter' );
function custom_plugin_load_filter( $plugins ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        //unset( $plugins['additional-order-confirmation-email/additional-order-confirmation-email.php'] ); // change my-plugin-slug
         $key = array_search( 'additional-order-confirmation-email/additional-order-confirmation-email.php' , $plugins );
            if ( false !== $key ) {
                unset( $plugins[$key] );
            }

    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

If I change it to `!in_array` it remains active for admin users (correct) but also for guests (incorrect).

Comment: Could I use a variation of this answer? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160802/117919

Comment: No. You wouldn't entirely disable the plugin based on the user role. Instead you'd perform that check just before the relevant functionality executes. Judging by the name of the plugin, that would be when the email is triggered. Also keep in mind that if this is for sending confirmation emails, and those emails can be triggered by back-end activity, the 'current user' is not necessarily the customer. So you wouldn't even be checking the user role, it would be the customer role. 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here anyway, so this is something you should ask the original author.

Comment: @JacobPeattie the name might be misleading - the plugin adds an additional (mandatory) billing field to the checkout which adds an additional recipient to the order confirmation and completed emails. I only want the additional billing email field (added by the plugin along with an additional html area in the checkout page) to be there based on the role of the logged in user. Unfortunately the original author isn't available at the moment so I will try and figure out :)

Comment: @JacobPeattie Also I didn't realise 3rd-party plugins were off topic as I don't usually post here, should I remove the question? Thanks

Comment: @Lyall Just be aware of the way you ask your question, this question is not really off-topic as you are asking about how to conditionally load a plugin in general. But if you were asking for specific changes to within a 3rd party plugin that would be.

Comment: Actually just reread the question and @JacobPeattie's comments, I really don't think it's clear in your question what you are wanting to do with this... If you do it this way it would seems like users with a role of `sales_events` would be receiving an additional confirmation order when **they** are the ones making an order.

Comment: @majick I've added some clarification regarding what the plugin does, thanks

Comment: @Lyall cool then given that particular use the answer should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to modify plugins if you can help it, as the plugin may be upated and you will lose your changes and need to redo them.

Fortunately, that is not necessary in this case anyway, as you can the filter active plugins option instead. You will need the plugin slug for this:

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'custom_plugin_load_filter' );
function custom_plugin_load_filter( $plugins ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !in_array( 'sales_events', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        unset( $plugins['my-plugin-slug'] ); // change my-plugin-slug
    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

Note as this will run on the plugins page also, it will probably prevent anyone without the role from disabling the plugin (as it will appear to be inactive to them.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Comment: The other way would be to switch the logic around, have the plugin inactive and add the slug to the plugin array if the user has the role. Either should work.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, for the slug I've tried the folder name, Plugin Name and Text Domain but the plugin features are still visible as a guest. The role ID is definitely sales_events and the role display name is Sales (Events). Any ideas?

Comment: it's actually the folder name and filename combined. eg. `akismet/akismet.php` ... you can mouse over a plugin action link in the admin plugins page and look at the plugin field in the URL. eg. `?action=activate&plugin=akismet%2Fakismet.php` because `%2F` = `/` when URL-encoded.

Comment: Thank you - it still doesn't appear to be working. I changed the role to `customer` in case that's an issue, but it still shows in checkout for admin users and guests. Example link URL is `...wp-admin/plugins.php?action=deactivate&plugin=additional-order-confirmation-email%2Fadditional-order-confirmation-email.php&plugin_status=all&...` so I used the slug `additional-order-confirmation-email/additional-order-confirmation-email.php`

Comment: just to check where did you place the code? it has to be in your child theme's `functions.php` or in a file in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` to have an effect. if it's in a plugin, it will be running *after* the plugins are loaded anyway, which is too late. otherwise you have a mismatch in the user role slug or plugin slug and need to debug dump those, but they seem fine on the surface of things.

Comment: I have only tried it in the functions.php in the child theme

Comment: well it should work in either place... sounds like you will need to debug to make sure your role/plugin slug conditions are actually matching.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll find out how to do that and see what I can find

Comment: everything appears correct, I've tried with role of 'guest' or 'customer' and with several variations of slug (with/without leading slash etc. from other answers on here) but nothing will make this work. Does it work for you?

Comment: the user role part definitely works correctly (I used it in a different function) so I think there's something funny with the unset part?

Comment: you can do something like `error_log(print_r($plugins,true), 3, ABSPATH.'/plugin-debug.log');` at the start of the filter to see the array of active plugins and determine what the exact plugin slug should be to match.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer based on the term "Executing plugin" in your question title.

If you just want to run/execute a plugin for user roles, you don't need to prevent it from loading. My solution is to let WordPress load your plugin and manage it in your plugin.

So, you could have codes like this:

```
// In the main plugin file that loads and initiate plugin functionalities.

if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    return;
}

include 'plugin-file.php';
new myPlugin();
```

By using this solution, your plugin is active for all users, but it actually **works only** for users with `manage_options` capability.

It will not make plugin **Inactive** for some users, but it is a clean solution to run functionality (Execute) only for some users.

Comment: I like this idea a lot, thanks! But is there a way to use the name of the role rather than `current_user_can`? The reason I ask is that I have some sites with several different roles all basically copies of the 'Customer' role, but each one can do different things, has different payment gateways, sees different products etc. I only need a plugin to show for one of those roles.

Comment: @Lyall You can use user role instead of capability in `current_user_can` function. Like: `current_user_can( 'administrator' )`.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do that, because the current user is set after plugins and themes have already been loaded, so the function `current_user_can()` would throw and error.

Comment: You could do it this way, put only this inside your main plugin file: `add_action('init', function(){ current_user_can('manage_options') && require 'main-plugin-functions.php'; });`, where `main-plugin-functions.php` is the file with all your plugin's core functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and used @majick's code after some modification:

```php
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'custom_plugin_load_filter' );
function custom_plugin_load_filter( $plugins ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !in_array( 'sales_events', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        $index = array_search( 'plugin-name/plugin-file.php', $plugins );
        unset( $plugins[ $index ] );
        $plugins = array_values( $plugins );
    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

To find out the plugin name/path, right-click the activate or deactivate link of the plugin (WP-Admin > Plugins > Installed Plugins list) and paste it in a URL decoder like [this](https://www.urldecoder.io/) one and use the value in the "plugin=" parameter.